# Show list of file names uploaded across the site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, document

I have a requirement to show List of Document names uploaded in all the libraries across the site collection, sorted by Created Date in descending order. I am working with SharePoint online and this requirement needs to be setup as a tabular view. I guess OOTB there is no really a way to do this at the site collection level.

Can this be doable by using some code, search query, workflow or may be other approach, can someone please help, thanks in advance.

P.S: If this is doable via a third party add-in and if you have used any in the past, please suggest.

Comment: Are you using classic pages or modern pages ?

Comment: I am using Classic UI

Comment: Is this for files uploaded/created within the last 24h or is it a total inventory?

Comment: Hi Kasper, yes its for files uploaded to be specific, time frame wise I would say, last 7 days sorted by created in descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For classic pages, you can use a content search webpart to show all documents sorted by created date. To display the results in tabular view you will have to customize the display template. In your content search webpart you can set the search query something like `path:"https://mysharepointsite" ContentTypeId:0x0101* -FileExtension:aspx -FileExtension:css -FileExtension:js -FileExtension:html` which shows all documents excluding few file extensions under the site specified in the path parameter. You can then set the sort order as needed.

To show the results in tabular fashion, you will have to customize the display template to display based on your requirement. There is a [github project](https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates/Table%20Layout%20with%20Sorting%20Templates%20(CSWP)) I found which does the same, you can use that as a start point..

Comment: Do you know if there is a third party add-in that can be leveraged for this requirement? Just asking for info purposes, thanks for your input here.

Comment: You could use bamboo list roll up https://bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-online-cloud-parts/list-rollup-cloud-part/ . I do not work or affiliated to that company. I have seen some companies use it. Although I think it would be simpler to use content search than figure out how to use third party solution.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as answer.